# How to locate Oracle Instant Client in Python in Docker CI/CD pipeline

Tags: python, oracle, docker, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle DB to execute some SQL queries and fetch data through a python script . I have imported cx_Oracle and tried connecting.I got the error as - **Exception - DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html for help was raised.**

I downloaded instaclient and used that in my script and it worked using the below commands :

```
         LOCATION = r"C:\instantclient_19_5"

         os.environ["PATH"] = LOCATION + ";" + os.environ["PATH"]
```

But now I need to use this in CI CD pipeline. I have created a docker image for instaclient and python I am trying use this into my script. But I am not sure how to use add instaclient location in script (like the above code snippet) Could you please help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update: the latest release of Oracle's python driver, now known as [python-oracledb](https://pypi.org/project/oracledb/) doesn't need Instant Client by default, so install is a lot easier**

Regarding cx_Oracle finding Instant Client, if you were deploying to Windows (or macOS), you could have used the cx_Oracle 8 [`init_oracle_client()`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/module.html#cx_Oracle.init_oracle_client) function, which is preferred to fiddling with PATH.

However it seems you are deploying to Linux, meaning the system library search path needs to contain all library directories *before* the process start.  So you need to use `ldconfig` or set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as traditionally used on Linux.  The cx_Oracle doc [Installing cx_Oracle on Linux](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-linux) and [Locating the Oracle Client Libraries](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/initialization.html#locating-the-oracle-client-libraries) covers this.

Also see sample docker images for [Linux developers](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleLinuxDevelopers) and for basic [Oracle Instant Client](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/tree/master/OracleInstantClient/dockerfiles/19).  If you are not on an RPM based system, check out the sample Docker files in [Docker for Oracle Database Applications in Node.js and Python](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1).

In summary, download Oracle Instant Client Basic or Basic Light packages from [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html).  If you got the ZIP files then run something like:

```
RUN echo /opt/oracle/instantclient_19_8 > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oic.conf && \
    ldconfig
```

The details vary with what base Docker image you are using, and whether you want to install Instant Client from ZIP files or RPMs.